# setting distance between 2 views in android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Relative Layout and would like to set the distance between 2 views (An ImageView and an Button). Whatever I could research and see, is that the only relative directions can be set between 2 views and not distance. The distance can be set only between the vieance betw and parent layout. Is there a way, I can set the distween 2 views ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use margins. For example if you have two views side by side:

```
[ V1 ][ V2 ]
```

and you want:

```
[ V1 ]    [ V2 ]
```

Just set `android:layout_marginRight="x"` on `V1`, where `x` is the distance.